# Is it OK to use SomeID.attribute instead of getElementById("SomeID")

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I know using something like `document.getElementById("img1").attribute` is an standard way to access to elements, but what about `img1.attribute`? Is it OK to use it?

Few years ago I used to use `NameValue.attribute` (I mean when I had an element like this `<input name="NameValue">`) to get and set elements attributes but today I tested it on FF and it didn't work. So I tested `IdValue.attribute` on IE, FF and Chrome and it worked.

Comment: Note: adding tag names in the post title is unnecessary, since the system does that for you automatically.

Comment: i wouldn't trust it - it might just fail in strict mode.

Comment: It would be best if you used `document.getElementById`, you can use the ID/global var method but you never know when that will stop working and it might not work on all browser/devices

Comment: While you can do this, please don't. It's unconventional and might cause obscure bugs when you expand your code later.

Comment: Actually I'm creating a video tutorial on Web Design & Programming and I haven't teached "functions" yet, so I wanted to use IdValue.attribute to make learning easier for the users , But it seems I have to teach "functions" first,  Thank you all very much ,